# "Сколько себя помню" — выделяется запятыми или нет?

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли выделять оборот "сколько себя помню", например, в таком предложении:

Живописью я увлекаюсь сколько себя помню.

Answer (score 1):

Да,  запятую надо поставить:

***ЖИвописью я увлекаюсь (столько), // сколько  себя пОмню.***

1) Это сложноподчиненное предложение с местоименной связью, указательное слово пропущено, но его можно восстановить.

С одной стороны, этот оборот речи обладает некоторой устойчивостью, но его всё-таки не относят к таким оборотам речи, как *сколько угодно, какой угодно, где угодно*: Все мне дают взаймы ***сколько угодно*** (Г.);

2) **О цельных по смыслу сочетаниях**

Розенталь: Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.

1. Перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний запятая не ставится. Данное правило основано на том, что **фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

3) Но оборот "сколько себя помню" **к таким сочетания не относится,** так как сохраняет  **семантику, структуру и интонацию  придаточного предложения,** то есть произносится с паузой.

Он содержит бОльшее количество информации, чем возможные эквивалентные выражения: очень давно, с детства, с самого раннего детства. Это именно с тех пор, когда человек начинает себя помнить.

4)  Что касается конкретного предложения, то в нем **логическое ударение падает на слово "живописью"**, что связано с инверсией этого слова, поэтому на вторую часть логическое ударение не падает и смысловым центром оборот не является.

Примеры:

Пел я *столько, сколько себя помню.*

Я пела *всегда, сколько себя помню.*

*Сколько себя помню*, я помню эту жажду играть.

*Сколько себя помню* – всегда завидовал.

Я сбегала из того дома, *сколько себя помню.*

Answer (score 1):

*Живописью я увлекаюсь сколько себя помню.*

Запятая в данном случае не ставится, так как устойчивое сочетание *сколько себя помню* тесно примыкает к сказуемому, несёт важную смысловую нагрузку. Важно не столько то, что человек увлекается живописью, сколько то, что он увлекается ею давно. Выражение выделяется и интонационно.

В предложениях с другой структурой, где нет тесной смысловой связи данного фразеологизма со сказуемым, он обособляется. Произносится фраза уже с интонацией, характерной для вводных конструкций.

*А между тем, сколько себя помню, ничего иного от этих сидений перед столом не получал ― только унижение.*

Comment: *Запятая в данном случае не ставится, так как устойчивое сочетание...* — Было бы здорово, если бы Вы привели пример данного устойчивого сочетания без запятой из литературы или учебников. Я посмотрел больше сотни ссылок в гугло-книгах — запятая стоит абсолютно во всех случаях.

Comment: По-моему, "сколько себя помню" эквивалентно слову "всегда". Без этой части предложение теряет исходное значение и превращается просто в утверждение того, что человек увлекается живописью. А автор текста говорит не это. Поддерживаю версию Екатерины.

Comment: @grizzly, Вы нашли именно такой случай? Когда выражение стоит в конце предложения непосредственно после глагола-сказуемого, употреблённого в 1 лице, и перетягивает на себя ударение? Такая конструкция встречается редко. Я не нашла.

Comment: Да, много. Вот несколько примеров: *...я песни пишу, сколько себя помню.* (В.С. Высоцкий. Роман о девочках); *Такое бельё я нашу, сколько себя помню* (А. Орлов, Бронебойщики);*Я жил в этом доме, сколько себя помню* ("Иностранная литература").

Comment: Придаточное предложение тоже может тесно ПРИМЫКАТЬ к главному предложению, но из этого не следует вывод, что его не нужно отделять от главного запятой. Например: Мы вышли из дома рано, как только поднялось солнце. - Мы вышли из дома, как только поднялось солнце. В обоих предложениях запятая ставится. Или тоже не ставится? Тесно примыкает, без него главное "предложение теряет исходное значение"?

Comment: Не мы первые обсуждаем этот вопрос, например: Фотографирую(,) сколько себя помню. Сколько себя помню(,) я всегда любил фотографировать.- И там и там запятая. Сомнения, видимо, оттого, что в "сколько себя помню" подозревается цельное фразеологическое выражение, по смыслу равное "всю жизнь". Но это не оно".pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4798478.html Трудно найти не только тексты без обособления, но и обоснование того, что запятая не нужна

Comment: Ребята, мнится мне, что вы прекрасно понимаете меня и мою позицию. Она основана на общеизвестном правиле, гласящем, что при тесном смысловом взаимодействии сказуемого и устойчивого выражения запятая между ними не ставится. Фотографирую(,)сколько себя помню - видела на каком-то сайте. Неубедительно! В нашем примере не ставим запятую по типу выражения "иду куда глаза глядят". ― Мне труднее отвечать вам, нежели вы думаете; я просто иду куда глаза глядят. (А. И. Герцен. Кто виноват?)

Comment: Прекрасно понимаем и намеренно противоречим? Зачем? Это как-то неправильно, неэтично. Я думаю, что при обсуждении сложных тем надо с уважением относиться к мнениям оппонентов и хотя бы рассматривать их, а не настаивать на своей  точке зрения. И практику текста надо учитывать тоже, а не относиться к ней с пренебрежением. И еще различать обороты и придаточные предложения, ведь обороту легче стать устойчивым и присоединиться к сказуемому. Что касается ПРИСЛОВНЫХ придаточных, то они и так ТЕСНО СВЯЗАНЫ с опорным словом местоименной или изъяснительной связью, и с ними нужно обращаться  аккуратно.

Comment: Здесь определять что-либо на слух  не стоит. Я сначала тоже решила, что запятой не нужно, но потом изменила свое мнение. Не хочется СООБЩАТЬ всему миру, что он ЗАБЛУЖДАЕТСЯ, если очевидные доказательства этого отсутствуют. Нет у классиков готового решения для этого случая. И нет ни одного разбора, который подтверждал бы отсутствие запятой. Это придаточное (по  структуре и содержанию)  ведет себя именно как придаточное в сложном предложении, оно не имеет значения одного слова (замена будет неточной). Поэтому нет причин для перевода его в цельное по смыслу выражение (термин Розенталя).